# Simple golang HTTP server gets stuck after number of requests

Tags: http, go, file-descriptor

**Background**

I have a website written in Golang that throws:

`http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8080: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
...
...`

on CentOS (Production) and then do not accept any more connection. 
Stress test using `ApacheBench` also stuck at around the 16500th request on my testing machine (OSX, timeout as well but without this error).

---

I decided to make a minimal case on OSX.

I adapted the following code from https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I ran `ab -n 100000 -c 100 -s 10 http://localhost:8080` but its also stuck at around 16500th request.

I have tried raising file descriptor limit `ulimit` from 256 to 10000 by `ulimit -n 10000`. Things did not improve.

Is there any `close()` that I should call?

Comment: Don't use `ab`. It's a poor and outdated http load tester. Use something that at least has support for http/1.1.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I have switched to `wrk` and it worked fine. But do you have any ideas on the `Accept Error...`?

Comment: The error comes from the OS, and is exactly what it says: `too many open files`. I can't say for sure without knowing exactly what you're doing, but I presume the sockets just aren't being closed fast enough too keep pace with the new incoming connections